Fetching records from Text column and storing in separate column with comma separator
This is the sample data:
Create table #test (ID int, remark nvarchar(max))

Insert into #test 
values (1,'ITEM:11119:QTY:24 LABEL:00008402279208913782,ITEM:16400:QTY:90 LABEL:00008402279248620756 LABEL:00008402279248620701')

Insert into #test 
values (2,'ITEM:11118:QTY:24 LABEL:00008402279208913782,ITEM:16401:QTY:90 LABEL:00008402279248620756 LABEL:00008402279248620701')

Expected output:
ID  ITEM            LABEL
--------------------------
1   11119,16400     00008402279208913782,00008402279248620756,00008402279248620701  
2   11118,16401     00008402279208913782,00008402279248620756,00008402279248620701  

Logic for the expected output. Remark text column contains the ITEM and their Labels, we need to create 2 column 1 for Item and 1 for Label and all the values need to saved in the columns with comma separated. There could be 1 ITEM or 10 Item it can vary.
Logic tried:
WITH SplitItems AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ID,
        Item = SUBSTRING(value, CHARINDEX(':', value) + 1, CHARINDEX(':', value, CHARINDEX(':', value) + 1) - CHARINDEX(':', value) - 1),
        Label = RIGHT(value, LEN(value) - CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(value)))
    FROM #test
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(remark, ',')
),
AggregatedItems AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        Items = STRING_AGG(Item, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Item) --AS Items
    FROM SplitItems
    GROUP BY ID
),
AggregatedLabels AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        Labels = STRING_AGG(Label, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Label]) --AS Labels
    FROM SplitItems
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.Items AS ITEM,
    L.Labels AS LABLE
FROM AggregatedItems A
JOIN AggregatedLabels L ON A.ID = L.ID;

I was able to calculate Item correctly, but I am not able to get label. Can someone please help me with this?

Why would you continue on this denormalized data storage, if anything your "new" format is even worse than the original, because you have no way of knowing which item belongs to which label. I'm a bit impressed you managed to get microsoft to backport STRING_AGG to your sql server 2008 installation though

Thats the requirement from customer

As @siggemannen already commented, STRING_AGG() was introduced in SQL Server 2017. What is your actual SQL Server version (and/or compatibility level)?

Since I see you are using string_agg() I doubt you are using 2012. Here is an option using a bit of JSON
Example
with cte as (
Select A.ID
      ,C.*
      ,Itm = lag(value,1) over (partition by ID order by [key])
 From  #Test A
 Cross Apply ( values ( '["'+replace(replace(replace(remark,',',':'),' ',':'),':','","')+'"]') ) B(NS) 
 Cross Apply OpenJSON(NS) C
)
Select ID
      ,Item  = string_agg( case when Itm='Item'  then value end ,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) 
      ,Label = string_agg( case when Itm='Label' then value end ,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) 
 From  cte 
 Group By ID

Results
ID  Item            Label
1   11119,16400     00008402279208913782,00008402279248620701,00008402279248620756
2   11118,16401     00008402279208913782,00008402279248620701,00008402279248620756

